# Is it possible to bind a pushID to a userUid in a Firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to create a PushID from the user's UID in another branch of my database.

So far I have done this:

```
DatabaseReference userUUID = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(user.getUid());
        
        String pushUser = userUUID.push().getKey();
        
        HashMap<String, Object> withdrawMap = new HashMap<>();
        withdrawMap.put("id", pushUser);
        withdrawMap.put("balance", "5000");
        withdrawMap.put("email", emailMP);
        withdrawMap.put("date", dateString);
        withdrawMap.put("statut", "Pending");
        withdrawMap.put("image", mediumPackImage);
        
        referenceWithdraw.child(pushUser)
            .setValue(withdrawMap)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {}
```

Here is my database in .json format(the first and second are from 2 different users)

```
{
  "Withdraw" : {
    "-Mn1-FONHwx1-EmwZKND" : {
      "amount" : "5000",
      "date" : "27/10/2021",
      "email" : "example@gmail.com",
      "id" : "-Mn1-FONHwx1-EmwZKND",
      "statut" : "Pending"
    },
    "-Mn1-ZI4lkbv4P76UMQl" : {
      "amount" : "5000",
      "date" : "27/10/2021",
      "email" : "example@gmail.com",
      "id" : "-Mn1-ZI4lkbv4P76UMQl",
      "statut" : "Pending"
    }
  }
}
```

```
referenceWithdraw = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Withdraw");
```

I would like to say that logically the child is an ID created from the Uid of the Firebase user(the code makes it clear in any case)

**Now imagine that I want to retrieve users' PushIds and show content**

```
referenceHistory = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Withdraw").child("????");
```

**
I have to put what in the second child to be able to retrieve the pushIDs that are created from the user ID?**

Hoping that I explained myself well

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data), to see it how it exactly looks like.

Comment: It's good I modified!

Comment: There are two children under the "Withdraw" node. Which of them would you like to get?

Comment: the children under "Withdraw" are IDs created from the Uid of the Firebase user. And so I would like to recover his respective ID for the user

Comment: No, under the "Withdraw" node, there are two pushed IDs, `-Mn1-FONHwx1-EmwZKND` and `-Mn1-ZI4lkbv4P76UMQl`. There is no UID present in your schema. Not higher in the hierarchy nor lower. So which one of those two children are you interested in?

Comment: Sorry, I don't explain myself well in English. Is there a way for example to retrieve the pushID of the first one which is "-Mn1-F0NHwx1-EmwZKND" and connect to user.getUid() from which it was created?

Comment: Are you storing `"-Mn1-F0NHwx1-EmwZKND"` in a variable? Besides that, what do you mean by "connect to user.getUid() from which it was created"?

Comment: I created during the registration a branch "Users" and in this branch there are children who store data, the children are the Uid. From this Uid by "reference.child(user.getUid).addEventListener... I retrieve the data stored in the Uid respectively of the user then displayed in the application. There I want to do the same principle except that in my problem the pushID I do not know how to retrieve it

Comment: I'm asking you again :) So which one of those two children are you interested in?

Comment: Sorry, the first one interests me

Comment: Ok, thank you for answering. Besides that, are you storing `"-Mn1-F0NHwx1-EmwZKND"` in a variable so it can be sure in a reference? Or is any of the `amount`, `date`, `email` values stored in a variable?

Comment: Sorry for the response time, only email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to get the data that corresponds to a single user with a specific email address, please use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference withdrawRef = rootRef.child("Withdraw");
Query queryByEmail = withdrawRef.orderByChild("email").equalTo("example@gmail.com");
queryByEmail.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : task.getResult().getChildren()) {
                String id = ds.child("id").getValue(String.class);
                Log.d("TAG", id);
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

According to your comment:

> The first one interests me.

Since both children have the same email addresses, then the result in the logcat will be:

```
-Mn1-FONHwx1-EmwZKND
-Mn1-ZI4lkbv4P76UMQl
```

If you want only the first result, you either add a `.limit(1)` call to your existing query, or you make sure you have unique email addresses.

Comment: Hello, sorry for the response time I was unavailable. the "get()" is not available, do you know what it can be replaced with? Apart from this the code looks very good to me !

Comment: You cannot use `get()`, most likely because you aren't using the latest Firebase Realtime Database dependencies. Try to use the latest version, and tell me if it works.

Comment: OKAY THAT'S GOOD! Thank you for giving me your time over several days.

Comment: I validated your answer hoping that it will help other people